# How to replace the first underscore in a column with a dash, and the second underscore with a blank space

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, format, str-replace

I hace a data frame with this rows and columns

```
Phascolarctobacterium_Lachnoclostridium_Non  0.371  -0.78   -21.908*    1.675
Intestinibacter_Phascolarctobacterium_cop   -0.84   -0.316  -16.871**   -2.101**
Sutterella_Subdoligranulum_Non              -20.593 3.658   1.258   -16.285***
```

by the way, I want the first row in the next format:

- first underscore replaced with a dash
- second underscore replaced with a blank space
- get * at the beginning of the first word and the end of the second
- get the "Non" replaced with "non"

Like this:

```
*Phascolarctobacterium-Lachnoclostridium* non    0.371  -0.78   -21.908*    1.675
*Intestinibacter-Phascolarctobacterium* cop -0.84   -0.316  -16.871**   -2.101**
*SutterellaSubdoligranulum* non             -20.593 3.658   1.258   -16.285***
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[,1]<-sub("([^_]+)_([^_]+)_(Non)?", "*\\1-\\2* \\L\\3", df[, 1], perl=TRUE)
```

the results:

```
df
                                             V1      V2     V3        V4         V5
1 *Phascolarctobacterium-Lachnoclostridium* non   0.371 -0.780  -21.908*      1.675
2   *Intestinibacter-Phascolarctobacterium* cop  -0.840 -0.316 -16.871**   -2.101**
3              *Sutterella-Subdoligranulum* non -20.593  3.658     1.258 -16.285***
```